# How do command blocks work?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to get started using command blocks. I can't seem to figure out how to do basic things, such as changing game modes, sending messages, and giving items to people using the block ID. Nothing I have tried is working.

How do I use command blocks?

Comment: What exactly are you trying, that isn't working?

Comment: You may be using a forward slash (`/`)in front of your commands, like you do in chat. You should remove this when using command blocks.

Comment: @Timtech, you could remove the /, but it's not necessary to do so and does not stop it from working if you leave it in.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use them as you would use a regular command in chat.

**Example:**

- `/give [user] 1 2`

This gives [user] two of item id 1 when the command block is activated with redstone.

- `/gamemode [user] [0, 1, 2]`

This will change [user]'s gamemode to either 0 (Survival) 1 (Creative) or 2 (Adventure)

**Note and Edit:** Buttons S (Survival) C (Creative) and A (Adventure) work as well as SevenSidedDie has noted for `/gamemode`

Comment: Note that `/gamemode` also accepts [`s`, `c`, `a`], which make it easier to avoid mistakes than using the number codes.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Thanks! I have updated the answer to make it better

Comment: And remember to supply it with redstone power